# How to match ios5 max zoomlevel MKMapView in ios6

Tags: ios5, mkmapview, ios6

It seems that the max zoomlevel (where you see max details) is different on iOS 6; I am not able to get as close to the surface as in iOS 5.

Does anybody know a way to match the max zoomlevel of iOS 5 in iOS6?

If I set a span of delta lon/lat 0.000001, 0.000001 (which is far beyond the max zoomlimit)

I get these results back from the mapview.region.span

```
// ios 5: actual span after zoom 0.002747, 0.001277
// ios 6: actual span after zoom 0.003460, 0.001608
```

the next matchable zoomlevel supported by Google is:

```
// actual span after zoom 0.005493, 0.002553
```

That is quite a jump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following post describes the solution for iOS 7 and up:

[How to get to the max zoomlevel on iOS MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658329/how-to-get-to-the-max-zoomlevel-on-ios-7-mkmapview)

It uses the MKMapCamera to determine to zoom level.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem on iOS 6 and found no way to fix it.
Just installed Xcode 4.6 DP1 and tested my App with Simulator 6.1 . Max zoomlevel now seems to be (nearly) the same .